# MacOS - unable to reach other terminals on the same LAN

Tags: macos, network

The problematic terminals, one Mac (Big Sur 11.x, a physical Mac Pro) and several Wins (Win10 19xx), are hooked to a (very basic) LAN switch with their IPs manually assigned on the same network - so just a simple mesh of direct LAN connections as shown below:

```
Internet:
Destination        Gateway            Flags        Netif Expire
default            192.168.8.1        UGScg          en2       
127                127.0.0.1          UCS            lo0       
127.0.0.1          127.0.0.1          UH             lo0       
169.254            link#15            UCS            en2      !
169.254            link#23            UCSI          en17      !
192.168.8          link#15            UCS            en2      !
192.168.8.1/32     link#15            UCS            en2      !
192.168.8.1        30:a1:fa:6f:ac:e8  UHLWIir        en2   1188
192.168.8.115      fc:44:82:13:a8:7b  UHLWIi         en2   1187
192.168.8.191/32   link#15            UCS            en2      !
192.168.23         link#23            UCS           en17      !
192.168.23.1       a0:ce:c8:1:75:ef   UHLWIi        en17   1162
192.168.23.2/32    link#23            UCS           en17      !
192.168.23.2       0:e0:4c:6c:3e:d6   UHLWI          lo0       
192.168.56         link#31            UC         vboxnet      !
224.0.0/4          link#15            UmCS           en2      !
224.0.0/4          link#23            UmCSI         en17      !
224.0.0.251        1:0:5e:0:0:fb      UHmLWI         en2       
239.255.255.250    1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa    UHmLWI         en2       
239.255.255.250    1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa    UHmLWI        en17       
255.255.255.255/32 link#15            UCS            en2      !
255.255.255.255/32 link#23            UCSI          en17      !
```

However the one Mac can’t reach any of the  Wins, but the Wins can reach Mac:

[image]

[image]

Things I’ve tried with no luck:

- Turn off the firewall on Mac
- Use another LAN interface on Mac
- Assign IPs from another network range

Any ideas on the possible causes or tricks I need to pull? Like do I have to manually add the route to the Windows terminals on Mac? Or anything else to check to get down to the bottom of this? Any direction would be much appreciated!

**Edit**

There are two interfaces on Mac - one LAN and other WIFI:

```
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 16384
    options=1203<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TXSTATUS,SW_TIMESTAMP>
    inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000 
    inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 
    inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
gif0: flags=8010<POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST> mtu 1280
stf0: flags=0<> mtu 1280
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 options=6467<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,TSO4,TSO6,CHANNEL_IO,PARTIAL_CSUM,ZEROINVERT_CSUM>
    ether 00:e0:4c:6c:3e:d6 
    inet6 fe80::10ae:69e9:4c9f:b2c6%en17 prefixlen 64 secured scopeid 0x17 
    inet 192.168.23.2 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.23.255
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex>)
    status: active
// ...
awdl0: flags=8943<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,PROMISC,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 32:f5:ee:c8:f1:92 
    inet6 fe80::30f5:eeff:fec8:f192%awdl0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x15 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
llw0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
    ether 32:f5:ee:c8:f1:92 
    inet6 fe80::30f5:eeff:fec8:f192%llw0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x16 
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: autoselect
    status: active
bridge0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    options=63<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,TSO4,TSO6>
    ether 02:38:b3:64:88:01 
    Configuration:
        id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 hellotime 0 fwddelay 0
        maxage 0 holdcnt 0 proto stp maxaddr 100 timeout 1200
        root id 0:0:0:0:0:0 priority 0 ifcost 0 port 0
        ipfilter disabled flags 0x0
    member: en3 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 13 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en4 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 7 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en5 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 19 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en6 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 20 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en7 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 11 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en8 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 8 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en9 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 9 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en10 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 14 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en11 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 16 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en12 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 17 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en13 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 18 priority 0 path cost 0
    member: en14 flags=3<LEARNING,DISCOVER>
            ifmaxaddr 0 port 10 priority 0 path cost 0
    nd6 options=201<PERFORMNUD,DAD>
    media: <unknown type>
    status: inactive
// ...
vboxnet0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00 
    inet 192.168.56.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.56.255
```

The network map is darn simple just each and every terminal hooked to the switch:

```
           [Mac]
             |
             | 
[Win A]-- [Switch]---[Win C]
             |
             |
           [Win B]
```

And the ARP cache:

```
? (169.254.95.116) at 9c:fc:e8:9b:46:0 on en2 [ethernet]
homerouter.cpe (192.168.8.1) at 30:a1:fa:6f:ac:e8 on en2 ifscope [ethernet]
desktop-ntkku2d (192.168.8.141) at 48:5f:99:47:b4:8b on en2 ifscope [ethernet]
imutazione (192.168.8.162) at 3c:22:fb:67:99:ff on en2 ifscope [ethernet]
ct-rda-foa-aes-cn (192.168.8.172) at 2a:1a:23:b4:b5:ad on en2 ifscope [ethernet]
? (192.168.23.3) at a0:ce:c8:1:75:ef on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
? (224.0.0.251) at 1:0:5e:0:0:fb on en2 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
? (239.255.255.250) at 1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa on en2 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
? (239.255.255.250) at 1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa on en0 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
```

Comment: I need a network map.  Your Mac appears to have 2 interfaces on different subnets. Is that right? Which addresses as the Windows boxes 192.168.23.1 and 3? And is the Mac 192.168.23.2? What is the 192.168.8 subnet? Is that LAN physically separate? Output of `ifconfig` and `arp -a` would help. Finally is that a real Mac? Which one?

Comment: @Gilby thanks for getting back - pls see edit and yes it's a real Mac with two interfaces (one WIFI, which works like a charm on `192.168.8.*`, and one physically separate LAN) with the offending LAN IP `192.168.23.2` and Windows boxes start from `192.168.23.3` and on.

Comment: 1) Need to think about it.  2) But, your original routing table has en17 - this is now en0. Something has changed there.  3) Regarding being a Mac, I was surprised that the MAC address 00:e0:4c:6c:3e:d6 is from a Realtek device - I thought all Macs has Apple as the vendor of the network device. 4) The ARP table shows the Mac can translate there 192.168.23.3 IP address to a MAC address for the Windows box. So I would expect ping 192.168.23.3 to work.

Comment: 1) appreciate that! 2) yes because I tried a usb LAN adapter to isoate the issue but still no luck … 3) again from using the usb LAN which is apparently a Realtek device 4) so what should I do from here? Can’t access any of the service/port on the Win machines from Mac either so looks like they are not just unpingable from Mac but also reachable … will try to connect a Linux/iPadOS device up to the network isolate further